# How to restrict user to check/uncheck other checkboxes in CheckBoxList until SelectedIndexChanged of previous click is not finished

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a **CheckBoxList** dynamically created. When user check/Uncheck any checkbox, "*OnSelectedIndexChanged*" Event is run for that specific checkbox. This event is a bit lengthy involving database accesses and doing certain calculations on a global decimal variable. Till this event is not completed, I don't want user to check/uncheck any other checkboxes in this **CheckBoxList** as this is effecting calculations. How can I restrict user from doing so? How can I disable the complete **CheckboxList** as a whole till the event is not completed? Please note that certain Checkboxes in the list may already be disabled depending on some conditions.

Comment: I think you mean to say “until this event is completed”... otherwise the user would only be able to check checkboxes while the event handler is running, which is a bit odd.

Comment: Are we talking about `CheckBoxList` from **WebForms**? You should mension this in your question. Anyway, I'm sure there is some kind of `CheckBoxList.Enabled` property for this.

Comment: Since you’re doing this on a post back event, the user can’t interact with the page while the event handler is running. Are you seein some other behavior?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Changed Until to Till. thanx

Comment: @HereticMonkey When I check the checkboxes quickly, the calculation on a global decimal variable is not correct, but when I check the boxes slowly giving few seconds break, calculation is correct. The calculation is done in the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" Event.

Comment: @vasily.sib  No, not on Webforms,  I am Using web controls on webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it successfully by adding a client-side onclick script as follow
`

```
<div id="myCBL" style="width: 90%; display: inline-block;">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Payees" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LstPayees_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="ListBoxinline" onclick="WaitForEvent()">
</asp:CheckBoxList> </div>
```

The script added is as below:

```
 function WaitForEvent() {
        var nodes = document.getElementById("myCBL").getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i].disabled = true;
        }
```

The checkboxes themselves get enabled after the OnSelectedIndexChanged method gets completed.